# ¿Cómo puedo hacer el promedio de una columna para cada valor distinto de otra fila en Python?

Tags: dataset

[Necesito hallar el promedio de los "births" para cada "year", para el año 2000, 20001...,2014.
Necesito solo contemplar los valores de "birth" que corresponden a cada año
[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpNAI.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpNAI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es agrupar por año y calcular el promedio:

```
df.groupby('year')['births'].mean()
```